# Из файла .py сделан .exe Антивирус ругается

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

После создания файла .exe ругается антивирус на троян. Использовал pyinstaller. Скомпилировал код, в котором нет tkinter и антивирус не ругается уже. Подскажите, почему так.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: гуглите и будет вам счастье. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156685/virus-warnings-after-trying-to-run-py-program-converted-to-an-exe-file